# Adding escape characters into select

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, escaping

My data if similar to below

```
firstName | middleName | lastName |
__________|____________|__________|
   Bob    |   michael  |  Smith   |
   John   |    sam     |  Cook    |
```

If I want to write a query that returns results that look like this

```
firstName | middleName | lastName |
__________|____________|__________|
 ('Bob',  |  'michael',| 'Smith') |
 ('John', |  'sam',    | 'Cook')  |
```

How would I write the escape characters that would also include a paren? Research tells me I'm going to be doing a number of single tics in a row, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 quotes to escape a quote, so `SELECT '(''' + firstName + ''',' AS firstName, ...`